# Webpack source maps: available in Firefox, missing in Chrome

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, firefox, webpack

I don't understand why I'm able to see all my source maps (maps from TypeScript to JavaScript) in Firefox, but they're mostly missing in Chrome.

Here's just part of what Firefox sees (it won't all fit on one screenshot if I open all of the folders):

[image: Firefox source maps]

And here's all that Chrome can see from the same website (the `assets` folder is just images, not code):

[image: Chrome source maps]

I'm simply using the webpack `devtool: 'source-map'` option. My attempts to use `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` instead have only made things worse, not better.

I'll post my full `webpack.config.js` here, but it's pretty big and I doubt it's all relevant. It's a `webpack.config.js` which has its roots in an old Angular project, simplified from that, but keeping parts that were there for handling things like `.scss` files.

I must confess that I am by no means an expert on webpack, I've just followed existing templates and modified them as needed. I have little doubt this config could be much simplified and improved.

The full source code for the project can be found here: https://github.com/kshetline/aw-clock/tree/gps

```js
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const postcssImports = require('postcss-import');

const entryPoints = ['inline', 'polyfills', 'sw-register', 'styles', 'vendor', 'main'];
const baseHref = '';
const deployUrl = '';
const projectRoot = process.cwd();
const maximumInlineSize = 10;
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

const postcssPlugins = function (loader) {
  // noinspection JSValidateTypes
  return [
    postcssImports({
      resolve: (url, context) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let hadTilde = false;
          if (url && url.startsWith('~')) {
            url = url.substr(1);
            hadTilde = true;
          }
          loader.resolve(context, (hadTilde ? '' : './') + url, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              if (hadTilde) {
                reject(err);
                return;
              }
              loader.resolve(context, url, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                }
                else {
                  resolve(result);
                }
              });
            }
            else {
              resolve(result);
            }
          });
        });
      },
      load: (filename) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // noinspection JSValidateTypes
          loader.fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
              return;
            }
            const content = data.toString();
            resolve(content);
          });
        });
      }
    }),
    postcssUrl({
      filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('~'),
      url: ({ url }) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'node_modules', url.substr(1));
        return path.relative(loader.context, fullPath).replace(/\\/g, '/');
      }
    }),
    postcssUrl([
      {
        // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
        filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('/') && !url.startsWith('//'),
        url: ({ url }) => {
          if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//) || deployUrl.startsWith('/')) {
            // If deployUrl is absolute or root relative, ignore baseHref & use deployUrl as is.
            return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${url}`;
          }
          else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
            // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
            return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
              `/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
          }
          else {
            // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
            // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
            return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
          }
        }
      },
      {
        url: 'inline',
        // NOTE: maxSize is in KB
        maxSize: maximumInlineSize,
        fallback: 'rebase',
      },
      { url: 'rebase' },
    ]),
    autoprefixer({ grid: true }),
  ];
};

// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
module.exports = {
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  performance: { hints: false },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.ts',
      '.js'
    ],
    symlinks: true,
    modules: [
      './src',
      './node_modules'
    ],
    alias: rxPaths(),
    mainFields: [
      'browser',
      'module',
      'main'
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      './node_modules'
    ],
    alias: rxPaths()
  },
  entry: {
    main: [
      './src/main.ts'
    ],
    polyfills: [
      './src/polyfills.ts'
    ],
    styles: [
      './src/styles.scss'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'public'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    crossOriginLoading: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash:20].[ext]',
          limit: 10000
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash:20].[ext]',
          limit: 10000
        }
      },
      {
        exclude: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exclude: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              precision: 8,
              includePaths: []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exclude: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exclude: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'stylus-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              paths: []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        include: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        include: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        include: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        include: [
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/styles.scss')
        ],
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'embedded',
              plugins: postcssPlugins,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'stylus-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              paths: []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, '/server/**/*']
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          context: 'src',
          to: '',
          from: 'assets/**/*',
          globOptions: {
            dot: true,
            ignore: [
              '.gitkeep',
              '**/.DS_Store',
              '**/Thumbs.db'
            ],
            debug: 'warning'
          }
        },
        {
          context: 'src',
          to: '',
          from: 'favicon.ico'
        }
      ]
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin({}),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      exclude: /([\\/])node_modules([\\/])/,
      failOnError: false,
      onDetected: false,
      cwd: projectRoot
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      hash: false,
      inject: 'head',
      compile: true,
      favicon: false,
      minify: false,
      cache: true,
      showErrors: true,
      chunks: 'all',
      excludeChunks: [],
      title: 'Webpack App',
      xhtml: true,
      chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
        // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
        const leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf((left.names && left.names[0]) || left.toString());
        // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
        const rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf((right.names && right.names[0]) || right.toString());

        return Math.sign(leftIndex - rightIndex);
      }
    }),
    function () {
      this.plugin('done', stats => {
        if (stats.compilation.errors && stats.compilation.errors.length > 0) {
          if (stats.compilation.errors.length === 0)
            console.error(stats.compilation.errors[0]);
          else {
            console.error(stats.compilation.errors.map(err =>
              err && typeof err === 'object' && err.message ? err.message : '').join('\n'));
          }

          process.exit(1);
        }
      });
    }
  ],
  node: {
    global: true
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```